# Inserting a link into Feed Dialog description

Tags: facebook-graph-api, dialog, feed

I am attempting to post a message to a user's wall that contains a set of different website links by means of a GET to the feed dialog endpoint (https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?...) or using FB.ui

e.g.

Hey I just read these stories:

www.example.com/story1

www.example.com/story2

Check them out!

Is it possible for a message to contain links?  I imagine any html inserted into fields such as "description" or "properties" does not work, but I just wanted to confirm if there is another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, please have a look at the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) url, the user would have to manually action the link (which hey would have to do anyways) but this should allow sharing of links.

The code would look something like

```
FB.ui({
      method: 'send',
      name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
      link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
});
```